# Multi variable summation/union

Tags: summation

I've seen a process like this in a proof: $$\sum_{k,l}|I_{k,l}|=\sum_k\sum_l|I_{k,l}|$$ and it says we can't do this if the summands are not positive numbers. I thought the left side is an abbreviation of the right side, but something's more in this I guess.

What exactly is $\sum_{k,l}$? and $\cup_{k,l}$? How should I understand these?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the observation refers to infinite sums. If $k,l$ are in a finite set of indexes, then
$$
\sum_{k,l}a_{i,k}=\sum_k\sum_l a_{k,l}.
$$
But this is no longer true if if $k,l$ move in infinite sets of indexes.
For instance,
$$
\sum_{k,l=0}^\infty a_{i,k}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{l=0}^\infty  a_{k,l}
$$
is guaranteed to hold if one the following conditions holds:

1. $a_{i,j}\ge0$.
2. $\sum_{k,l=0}^\infty |a_{i,k}|<\infty$.